# Mysql query to get multiple counts of fields in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

table name: testing

Create query (credit to @ankit.jbp for helping out in the same):

For creating table

```
CREATE TABLE testing   
( id int(11) NOT NULL,  
sub_id int(11) NOT NULL,  
status varchar(50) NOT NULL )  
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO testing   
(id, sub_id, status)   
VALUES (1, 1, 'NOT STARTED'), (1, 1, 'NOT STARTED'), (1, 1, 'NOT STARTED'), (1, 2, 'COMPLETE'), (1, 2, 'COMPLETE'), (2, 3, 'COMPLETE'), (2, 3, 'DEFAULT'), (3, 4, 'NOT STARTED');
```

| id | sub_id | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | NOT_STARTED |
| 1 | 1 | NOT_STARTED |
| 1 | 1 | NOT_STARTED |
| 1 | 2 | COMPLETE |
| 1 | 2 | COMPLETE |
| 2 | 3 | COMPLETE |
| 2 | 3 | DEFAULT |
| 3 | 4 | NOT_STARTED |

The id and sub_id are unique in their fields. There may be multiple sub_ids in 1 id.
I want to create an MySQL Query to tell me the counts of status ='COMPLETE' and total of both id and sub_id Group By sub_id and other information in the following desired output:

| total count of id | id | sub_id | total count of sub_id | total count of sub_id with status='COMPLETE' |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 0 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 4 | 1 | 0 |

I would appreciate the help in this query, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
select status, count(status)
from table 
group by status
order by status
```

the output should like

```
NOT_STARTED,4
COMPLETE,3
DEFAULT,1
```

aditional you can add a sum to have a total

Comment: I wanted the query output to be like the second table written in my question.

Comment: ```select count(id),sub_id, count(sub_id),count(status)
from table 
where status = 'COMPLETE'
group by status
order by status```  Just a rearangement, when you need the count of ids in front, you need to select it seperat and glue it together in a seperat table

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It would help, if you could provide what you have tried already.
Here are some suggestions to start with:

For creating the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `testing` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sub_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `testing` (`id`, `sub_id`, `status`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'NOT STARTED'),
(1, 1, 'NOT STARTED'),
(1, 1, 'NOT STARTED'),
(1, 2, 'COMPLETE'),
(1, 2, 'COMPLETE'),
(2, 3, 'COMPLETE'),
(2, 3, 'DEFAULT'),
(3, 4, 'NOT STARTED');
```

Those are no exact solutions, but you can take them as a starter.

```
select id,sub_id, status, count(id) from (SELECT * FROM `testing` where 
status !='COMPLETE') t union Select id,sub_id, status,count(id) from 
(SELECT * FROM `testing` where status ='COMPLETE') t2;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip and the create queries. I will add them to the question to make reproducing the issue easy.